# Assign the 'onmouseover' event handler

Tags: javascript

Please tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >

function createimg()
       {
         var img = new Image();
       img.src='link/to/image';
       img.alt='Next image';  img.id = 'span1'; img.style.zIndex = 10;
       img.style.position = 'absolute';  img.style.display='block'; img.style.top = '130px';
       img.style.padding='10px'; img.style.left='440px';    img.className ='dynamicSpan';
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        return img;
        }

    function al()
    {
     alert('loaded');
    }
   a = createimg();

    a.onmouseover = al();

</script>
```

In specific the last part, where I'm trying to assign the 'onmouseover' event handler of a, which is an image element.  It does not assign this event handler for some reason and just executes the function on page load instead.

What is wrong?

Tony

Comment: be careful with the hardcoded `id`, as having more than one element with the same id in the DOM will violate the HTML spec.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a.onmouseover = al;
```

When you write `al()` you are calling the function on the spot and assigning the *return value* of the function (which is undefined since there's no `return` statement) to `a.onmouseover`. Instead you want to assign the function itself so you just need to remove the parentheses.

Comment: that helps! but now my al function does not execute at all, not even on mouseover of image.  could anything else be wrong?

Comment: Sorted!! Works now! Thanks guys!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, your code is not formatted in a way that makes it easy to read.

But your problem is here:

```
a.onmouseover = al();
```

What you really want is:

```
a.onmouseover = al;
```

The `()` operator *invokes* the function.  So the expression `al()` is equal to the result of executing the function `al` -- which means the `al` function must be executed before its result (which, in this case, is `undefined`) can be assigned to `a.onmouseover`.

By contrast, if you just use `al`, the expression is equal to the *function object* `al`, which is what you actually want to assign to the event.  In that case, when the event is triggered, the `al` function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a.onmouseover = al;
```

instead of

```
a.onmouseover = al();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a.onmouseover = al;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

a.onmouseover = al();

With:

```
a.onmouseover = al;
```