# Combine JavaScript onload with namespace

Tags: javascript

I am using a namespace to hold some functions in JavaScript, all of which I want to run with `window.onload`. If I do this, everything works as expected:

```
SiteFn = {};

(function(context) {
    context.firstFn = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
    context.secondFn = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
})(SiteFn);

window.onload = function() {
    SiteFn.firstFn();
    SiteFn.secondFn();
};
```

However, when I try to group them into a single `init` function, it seems to get called *before* `window.onload`:

```
SiteFn = {};

(function(context) {
    context.firstFn = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
    context.secondFn = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
    context.start = function() {
        context.firstFn();
        context.secondFn();
    };
})(SiteFn);

window.onload = SiteFn.start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SiteFn.start()` **calls** the function and assigns the return value to `window.onload`. `()` after a function reference always calls the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign the 'onmouseover' event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534516/assign-the-onmouseover-event-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to actually call the method, just give a reference to it, and so

```
change this:
window.onload = SiteFn.start();
to this:
window.onload = SiteFn.start;
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have spotted that earlier!