# Loading external images into a tooltip onMouseOver event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-tools, onmouseover

I am building a dynamic tooltip for a car shopping website for a page that loads tons of photos based on search parameters.  The loaded images are thumbnails we host locally.

Where I am having trouble is adding functionality so when someone mouses over the thumbnail, the tooltip renders a larger image of the car, as well as the year, make, model and price.  These images are hosted on an external domain.

I am using the jQuery Tools Tooltip plug-in for the core functionality.  Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to these more intermediate JavaScript concepts, and I cannot seem to find any tutorials on Google helping with my usecase.

My HTML

```
<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/320x240" />
    <p>2012 Infiniti GSX $29,800</p>
</div><!-- #tooltip -->
<ul id="thumbs">        
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.web2carz.com/images/thumbs/22/80/thumb_large_70364184.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>               
</ul>​
```

My JavaScript:

```
// Image Tooltips
jQuery("#thumbs li a").tooltip({
    tip: '#tooltip',
    effect: 'fade',
    relative: true,
    position: 'bottom center',
    delay: 0,
    offset: [5, 150]
}).dynamic({ top: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });​
```

My initial assumption is to add a function like this ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534516/assign-the-onmouseover-event-handler)):

```
function loadImg() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src='http://placehold.it/320x240';
    img.id = 'toolImg';
    return img;
    document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML += img;
  }
```

Add the event handler to my anchor like: `<a href="#" onMouseOver="loadImg()">` and then append the loaded image to the tooltip:

`document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML += 'img';`

I just cant seem to find the proper next steps to achieve the functionality I want.

I have a jsfiddle with my current code set up as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/aRJ84/10/

### ANSWER

So I got it working, here is my functioning code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="thumbs">
 <li>
  <a href="#" onMouseOver="loadImg('http://placehold.it/720x480', 'Honda')">
   <img src="http://www.web2carz.com/images/thumbs/22/80/thumb_large_70364184.jpg" />          
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadImg(img, makeName) {
  var bla = "<img src=\"" + img + "\"/>";

  bla += "<br><p>This is  great car</p>" + makeName;

  document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML = bla;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your event handler definition to this:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="loadImg()">
```

It looks like what you are actually doing is just giving the `onMouseOver` event a *reference* to your function, which is not the same as telling it to ***call*** the function. Adding the parens should help.

I went to your jsFiddle to try some edits, but I don't see the `loadImg` function in your JavaScript. I don't want to do any harm, so I didn't make any changes. Hope this helps -

Comment: thanks for the response.  I updated my jsfiddle, and please feel free to edit it (if you felt so inclined), I am working locally.  I added in the parens, but still nothing...

Comment: Because there is no `loadImg` function. The stuff on your jsFiddle doesn't seem to match the description in your question. Best of luck -

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer helped send me in the right direction, so Ill just go ahead and accept as a solution :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. I've done the same thing myself - accepted the answer just for pointing me in the right direction. Very glad it all worked out -